# First Order Logic: Write a sentence which makes the domain a square number

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

The language has three unary function symbols f,g and h.
The domain is a square if the model is a model of this sentence and the domain is finite.

Comment: "The domain is a square" ???

Comment: See [Square number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_number): "In mathematics, a square number or perfect square is an integer that is the square of an integer; in other words, it is the product of some integer with itself. For example, $9$ is a square number, since it can be written as $3 \times 3$."

Comment: "Write a sentence which makes the domain a square number": $\forall x (x=9)$.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! It should be the cardinality of domain being a square number. I've already found a similar thread though. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305188/find-a-first-order-sentence-satisfied-by-models-with-square-domain?rq=1

Comment: Ok, thanks. Duplicate of [Find a first order sentence satisfied by-models with square domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305188/find-a-first-order-sentence-satisfied-by-models-with-square-domain)

Comment: The sentence $\forall x\forall y(x=y)$ works.The domain of any model of this sentence has cardinality $1$ which is a square number.